# Find $\delta$ s.t. $|x-2|<\delta$ means $|x^2+2x-18|<\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: limits, analysis

I need to find $\delta$ s.t. $|x-2|<\delta$ means $|x^2+2x-18|<\frac{1}{4}$ (as if I was asked to find $\delta$ when finding the limit at 2, with $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$). My issue is that this does not factor nicely, so I am having trouble. When I try to factor out $(x-2)$ I get $x^2+2x-18=(x-2)(x+4)+10$, and this is not helping me to obtain $\delta$. 
Thanks!

Comment: Note that if $x$ is close to $2$, then $x^2+2x$ is close to $8$, not $18$.

Comment: No such $\delta$ exists because, as Sobi stated, if $x\approx2$ then $x^2+2x-18\approx -10$.  If $x^2+2x-18=0$, then $x=-1\pm \sqrt{19}$ and $x\approx -5.36$ or 3.36.

Comment: yes I thing that the textbook question must have a typo. Hopefully the professor concurs.

Comment: You might have an interesting discussion in class if you tell your professor that $\delta=0$ does the trick....  That is, the mathematical assertion $|x-2|\lt0\implies|x^2+2x-18|\lt1/4$ is vacuously true, since $|x-2|\lt0$ is false for all $x$.  (On the other hand, when stated carefully, epsilon-delta theorems always call for a *positive* value of $\delta$. The OP here doesn't mention that condition; the question is, did the textbook forget as well?)

Answer (score -2):

**hint**

$$x^2+2x-8=(x-2)(x+4)$$
$$=(x-2)(x-2+6)$$
$$=(x-2)^2+6(x-2)$$

solve for $\delta$ the inequation

$$\delta^2+6\delta<\frac 14.$$

Comment: Can i know why this down.

Comment: OP is trying to prove that $x^2+2x\to 18$ when $x\to 2$, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Sobi The limit is $8$. i edited.

Comment: That's very nice, but it still does not address the issue from the post, since OP is clearly unaware of this.

Comment: yes I think the issue is our book question has a typo, explaining why I couldn't solve the actual question. Thanks though!